# Proving the relation between the Dirichlet eta function and the Riemann zeta function

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions, dirichlet-series

The problem I am trying to solve is: I need to prove the relation between the Dirichlet eta function and the Riemann zeta function $\eta(s) = \left(1-2^{1-s}\right) \zeta(s)$.

But I have no clue where to start or how to approach this problem. Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Nice question, can you show us anything that you've thought of?

Comment: @Jan I was trying to use the defintions of both the functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Assignment**:
>
> Prove the following fact:
>
> $$\eta\left(\text{s}\right):=\sum_{\text{n}\space\ge\space1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\text{n}-1}}{\text{n}^\text{s}}=\zeta\left(\text{s}\right)\left(1-2^{1-\text{s}}\right)$$
>
> Where $\eta\left(\text{s}\right)$ is the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) and $\zeta\left(\text{s}\right)$ is the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

---

**Solution**:

First, let's add the sum over all odd and even numbers:

$$\eta\left(\text{s}\right)=\underbrace{\sum_{\text{n}\space\ge\space1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{2\text{n}-1-1}}{\left(2\text{n}-1\right)^\text{s}}}_\text{odd part}+\underbrace{\sum_{\text{n}\space\ge\space1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{2\text{n}-1}}{\left(2\text{n}\right)^\text{s}}}_\text{even part}=\sum_{\text{n}\space\ge\space1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{2\left(\text{n}-1\right)}}{\left(2\text{n}-1\right)^\text{s}}+\sum_{\text{n}\space\ge\space1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{2\text{n}-1}}{\left(2\text{n}\right)^\text{s}}\tag1$$

Now, we know that $\left(-1\right)^{2\left(\text{n}-1\right)}=1\space\forall\space\text{n}\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\left(-1\right)^{2\text{n}-1}=-1\space\forall\space\text{n}\in\mathbb{N}$, so we can write:

$$\eta\left(\text{s}\right)=\sum_{\text{n}\space\ge\space1}\frac{1}{\left(2\text{n}-1\right)^\text{s}}-\sum_{\text{n}\space\ge\space1}\frac{1}{\left(2\text{n}\right)^\text{s}}\tag2$$

Now, Let's add and subtract the same thing on the RHS:

$$
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\eta\left(\text{s}\right)&=\sum_{\text{n}\space\ge\space1}\frac{1}{\left(2\text{n}-1\right)^\text{s}}-\sum_{\text{n}\space\ge\space1}\frac{1}{\left(2\text{n}\right)^\text{s}}+\underbrace{\sum_{\text{n}\space\ge\space1}\frac{1}{\left(2\text{n}\right)^\text{s}}-\sum_{\text{n}\space\ge\space1}\frac{1}{\left(2\text{n}\right)^\text{s}}}_{=\space0}\\
\\
&=\underbrace{\underbrace{\sum_{\text{n}\space\ge\space1}\frac{1}{\left(2\text{n}-1\right)^\text{s}}}_\text{odd part}+\underbrace{\sum_{\text{n}\space\ge\space1}\frac{1}{\left(2\text{n}\right)^\text{s}}}_\text{even part}}_{\text{odd part}\space+\space\text{even part}}-\left\{\sum_{\text{n}\space\ge\space1}\frac{1}{\left(2\text{n}\right)^\text{s}}+\sum_{\text{n}\space\ge\space1}\frac{1}{\left(2\text{n}\right)^\text{s}}\right\}\\
\\
&=\sum_{\text{n}\space\ge\space1}\frac{1}{\text{n}^\text{s}}-2\sum_{\text{n}\space\ge\space1}\frac{1}{\left(2\text{n}\right)^\text{s}}
\end{alignat*}
\tag3
$$

Now, by definition, the Riemann zeta function is given by:

$$\zeta\left(\text{s}\right):=\sum_{\text{n}\space\ge\space1}\frac{1}{\text{n}^\text{s}}\tag4$$

And we can use the fact that:

$$\frac{1}{\left(2\text{n}\right)^\text{s}}=\frac{1}{2^\text{s}\cdot\text{n}^\text{s}}=\frac{1}{2^\text{s}}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{n}^\text{s}}=\frac{2^{-\text{s}}}{\text{n}^\text{s}}\tag5$$

So:

$$
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\eta\left(\text{s}\right)&=\zeta\left(\text{s}\right)-2\sum_{\text{n}\space\ge\space1}\frac{2^{-\text{s}}}{\text{n}^\text{s}}\\
\\
&=\zeta\left(\text{s}\right)-2\cdot2^{-\text{s}}\sum_{\text{n}\space\ge\space1}\frac{1}{\text{n}^\text{s}}\\
\\
&=\zeta\left(\text{s}\right)-2^{1-\text{s}}\sum_{\text{n}\space\ge\space1}\frac{1}{\text{n}^\text{s}}\\
\\
&=\zeta\left(\text{s}\right)-2^{1-\text{s}}\zeta\left(\text{s}\right)\\
\\
&=\zeta\left(\text{s}\right)\left(1-2^{1-\text{s}}\right)
\end{alignat*}
\tag6
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Comment: However, this relation also holds for $0<\Re(s)<1$, but the equation of $\zeta$ you used only works for $\Re(s)>1$. I'm pretty sure there's a way to fix that, but still.

Comment: For completion: $$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^s} \operatorname{Re}(s)>0 \wedge s \neq 1$$